# Quick Media Solutions - The First Tool to Take Advantage of Write Access in v2.1 of the API!

Tags: app, website, python

### Website

http://quickmediasolutions.com

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Quick Media Solutions is my personal website where most of the web services and tools I have written reside. I recently rewrote the entire website in Python (using the Django framework) in order to organize things better and make it easier to add new services.

The site fully integrates with the Stack Exchange API - after creating an account on the site, you can authorize the site to access your Stack Exchange account.

The services currently provided include [an RSS feed of your inbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/135045/142114), an RSS feed for notifications, and an inbox sidebar that lets you comment directly from the page using the new write access introduced with v2.1 of the API.

#### License

Quick Media Solutions is closed source.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

Comment: The old version of your site was cool, but this is just awesome! Thanks George!

Comment: @Dynamic: No, thank *you* - I'm always glad to hear that something I've made is useful to somebody.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what was the first site built with?

Comment: @Dynamic: The first site was written in PHP, although most of it was just static HTML pages with a `.php` extension :)

Comment: Is there documentation on the 2.1 API that you're using anywhere? I can't find it. :(

Comment: @sblom: It is [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).