# API v2.1 supports write access, but is anyone using it?

Tags: discussion, api-v2.1, comments, write-access

Over the weekend, I attended an NHS "Hackday" where we tried to solve a problem one of the junior doctors brought. We hacked together a stack exchange alternative for medical doctors to ask questions.

The most obvious thought was to just set up a medical stack exchange but one of the key components of the problems was that asking a question should be very easy - a user should be able to do it from their phone. And so we quickly decided we would need something with a little bit extra than stack exchange.

In the end we didn't have enough time or digital ducktape to connect our alternative to a mobile phone.

On my more in depth searching this morning I see that API v2.1 does actually support writing of comments but I can't find many apps *actually* using it.

Could anyone provide me with some examples? Am I correct in thinking that only comments can be written and not questions?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As of [api-v2.2](/questions/tagged/api-v2.2), it's also possible to write questions and answers via the API.

---

There are at least a few examples in use, of API 2.1 apps, that write comments.  See:

- [The *Quick Media Solutions* app](https://stackapps.com/q/3552/7653)
- [The *StackX* Android app](https://stackapps.com/q/3901/7653)
- [The *SX.el* Emacs app](https://stackapps.com/q/3950/11299)

Re:

> Am I correct in thinking that only comments can be written and not questions?

Yes, that's correct.  Except for [the super-secret, official, Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/190200/148310) that's under development.  It presumably uses an API that's not publicly documented.

Comment: Well, and my app uses an undocumented route as well. I won't say anything more than that, however.

Comment: @NathanOsman, but you are using an API, not screen scraping, right?

Comment: Correct. It is an undocumented API method.

Comment: Is this answer outdated? Writing questions s is possible and it is documented.

Comment: @Malabarba, Not technically, since the Q is tagged API version 2.1. Updated the answer as well, so you can upvote. ;)